# Comparison of two csv file and output with differences?

Tags: python, csv, difference

I am comparing two csv files but the `update.csv` file is same as `new.csv`

```
import csv

with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1:
    old_csv = t1.readlines()

with open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    new_csv = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        line_in_new = 0
        line_in_old = 0
        while line_in_new < len(new_csv) and line_in_old < len(old_csv):
            if old_csv[line_in_old] != new_csv[line_in_new]:
                out_file.write(new_csv[line_in_new])
            else:
        line_in_old += 1
    line_in_new += 1
```

I want output same as the sample.

Sample :

Input:

old.csv

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
8,9,9
```

new.csv

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
5,6,7
8,9,7
```

Output:

update.csv

```
4,5,6,deleted
5,6,7,new added 
8,9,9,change
```

Please help me to get the only difference on `update.csv`

Comment: What do u mean by **difference**? please post a clear input sample and desired output.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('old.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('new.csv')

df1['flag'] = 'old'
df2['flag'] = 'new'

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

dups_dropped = df.drop_duplicates(df.columns.difference(['flag']), keep=False)
dups_dropped.to_csv('update.csv', index=False)
```

*Input*:

**old.csv**

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

**new.csv**

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
5,6,7
```

*Output*:

**update.csv**

```
a,b,c,flag
4,5,6,old
5,6,7,new
```

Comment: Thanks, Ashish,  If I want to show only differences means old & new.How i can get